# What is the keyboard shortcut to press the OK button in IntelliJ dialogue boxes?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

Is there a keyboard shortcut I can use to press the `ok` button in IntelliJ's dialogue boxes?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: As you show if with OK highlighted, just press Enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No special keyboard shortcuts.

<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select;
arrow keys to navigate.